# Access query inside return method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql, drupal-8

I have a backend Drupal site and react-native app as my frontend. I am doing a graphQL query from the app and was able to display the content/s in `console.log`. However, my goal is to use a call that query inside render return method and display it in the app but no luck. Notice, I have another REST API call `testName` and is displaying in the app already. My main concern is how to display the graphQL query in the app.

Below is my actual implementation but removed some lines.

```
...
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://192.168.254.105:8080/graphql'
});

client.query({
  query: gql`
    query {
      paragraphQuery {
        count
        entities {
          entityId
          ...on ParagraphTradingPlatform {
            fieldName
            fieldAddress
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `,
})
.then(data => {
  console.log('dataQuery', data.data.paragraphQuery.entities) // Successfully display query contents in web console log
})
.catch(error => console.error(error));

const testRow = ({
  testName = '', dataQuery // dataQuery im trying to display in the app
}) => (
  <View>
    <View>
      <Text>{testName}</Text> //  This is another REST api call.
    </View>
    <View>
      <Text>{dataQuery}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
)

testRow.propTypes = {
  testName: PropTypes.string
}

class _TestSubscription extends Component {
  ...
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.testList}
          ...
          renderItem={
            ({ item }) => (
              <testRow
                testName={item.field_testNameX[0].value}
                dataQuery={this.props.data.data.paragraphQuery.entities.map((dataQuery) => <key={dataQuery.entityId}>{dataQuery})} // Here I want to call the query contents but not sure how to do it
              />
            )}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return ({
    testList: state.test && state.test.items,
    PreferredTest: state.test && state.test.PreferredTest
  })
}
...
```

Comment: what does it mean "no luck"? is error shown? or what? anyway requesting something in `render()` is bad idea since request is async so when data comes `render()` has already been finished. And there is one more reason not making anything heavy in `render()`: it's run typically(until you have `PureComponent` there) much more often than you can expect.

Comment: `error: bundling failed: SyntaxError` in this line `dataQuery={this.props.data.data.paragraphQuery.entities.map((dataQuery) => <key={dataQuery.entityId}>{dataQuery})}`

Comment: ***until you have PureComponent there* << you mean will create a separate component for the query then just call it in my main component?

Comment: @skyboyer cant we make the query data as props?

Comment: can you add complete error message in your question? 
no, I don't mean you need additional component to handle data loading

Answer (score 1):

There are few different things that are wrong there.

1. `Syntax error` is because your `<key>` tag is not properly closed here:

   ```
   (dataQuery) => <key={dataQuery.entityId}>{dataQuery})
   ```
2. And... there is no `<key>` element for React Native. You can check at [docs Components](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs) section what components are supported. Btw there is no such an element for React also.
3. Requesting data is async. So when you send request in `render()` this method finishes execution much earlier before data is returned. You just cannot do that way. What can you do instead? You should request data(in this element or its parent or Redux reducer - it does not matter) and after getting results you need to set state with `.setState`(if it happens inside the component) or `.dispatch`(if you are using Redux). This will call `render()` and component will be updated with data retrieved. There is additional question about displaying spinner or using other approach to let user know data is still loading. But it's orthogonal question. Just to let you know.
4. Even if requesting data was sync somehow(for example reading data from LocalStorage) you must not ever do this in `render()`.This method is called much more frequently that you can expect so making anything heavy here will lead to significant performance degradation.

So having #3 and #4 in mind you should run data loading/fetching in [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) or as a part of handling say button click.